# Complie .pyx to .pyd incuding relative imports

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cython, cythonize

Here's my question in learning sklearn.
There are some cython code in sklearn , for example:

```
 sklearn/tree/
     _utils.pyd
     _tree.pyd
     _test.pyx
```

the `_test.pyx` includes code:

```
   from ._utils cimport log
```

Now I want to complie `_test.pyx` to `_test.pyd` by using Cython.
But it doesn't work, the error is:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
np.import_array()

from ._utils cimport log
^
------------------------------------------------------------

sklearn\tree\_test.pyx:30:0: 'sklearn\tree\_utils.pxd' not found
```

Here is my compilation code in `cythonbuild.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy 

extensions = [
    Extension("tree", ["_criterion.pyx"],
        include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()],
)
]
setup(
    name = "test",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

Then I ran the command in cmd:

```
python cythonbuild build_ext --inplace
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How do you compile it ?

Comment: please edit your post including the new snippet of code for a better vizualisation

Comment: Thanks,I updated my complie code in the question below